# Does Meteor Allow Self Signed SSL Certificates

Tags: sockets, ssl, meteor, react-native, websocket

I am currently trying to connect a React Native app to a Meteor server. I am able to connect to the web socket using a browser Web Socket Client. However, my react native app which uses the react-native-meteor boilerplate is unable to connect to the web socket (it is able to connect to web sockets on the local network). I am using a self-signed SSL certificate. Could this be preventing a successful connection from the phone app to the web socket?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the answer is yes. I added an SSL certificate to my server and was finally able to connect to the server through a secure websocket.